# PNPM and corrupted files

Tags: pnpm

I'm trying to use pnpm on a large dependency tree. Everything installs correctly, however some files are corrupted and can't be opened (they appear as binary files).

Is there a way to check the integrity of the store, or debug the installation process ?

Node v12, pnpm v6.0.2, windows 10

Comment: got some leftovers in \.pnpm ? edit: saw this? https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/issues/2343

Comment: Using another store fix the issue. however, i'd like to have a way to detect such corrupted case/files ..

Comment: There is a command that checks integrity of files in the store: `pnpm store status`

But how were your files corrupted? By a postinstall scripts?

Comment: Thanks, this command show me the modified package. however, I am not sure of the best method to fix them. I have no clue on how the files were corrupted. I am behind a firewall and a reverse proxy with a virus scanner which sometimes returns 404 because of timeout, but pnpm doesn't show me any errors.

Comment: run `pnpm store status` , if there are some modified pages in the store , it will ask you to run `pnpm install --force` to fix. Just as @Zoltan Kochan said

Answer (score 1):

`pnpm store status` is what you're after.